# Ansible regex search unknown escape character

Tags: regex, ansible

I need to extract SERVER1 from a string like this: directory/SERVER1-info.dat
According to regex101.com, this regex string correctly parses it:  `(?<=\/)(\w*)(?=-)` but in Ansible,  `"{{ filename | regex_search('?<=/')('\w*')('?=-') }}"` causes an error "found unknown escape character 'w'\n\n errors.

I've tried removing the single quotes and doing `\\w`, all these give more templating errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select the string between the slash `/` and dash `-`, the task below does the job

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ path|regex_replace(regex, replace) }}"
      vars:
        path: directory/SERVER1-info.dat
        regex: '^(.*)/(.*)-(.*)$'
        replace: '\2'
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: SERVER1
```

If you'd like to avoid regex the task below gives the same result

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ (path|basename).split('-').0 }}"
      vars:
        path: directory/SERVER1-info.dat
```